# Django Include file repeating itself in production only

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I created a sidebar include file for my sites parts page and used the `regroup` tag to list parts by category. It works great locally - see screenshot below.  But in production it repeats the category and parts several times - see http://www.dev.ddmpowertools.com/products/parts/.  I am lost as to the reason for this.  Thank you for your help.

**My sidebar include file's code:**

```
{% regroup parts by category as category_list %}
<ul class="c-sidebar-menu collapse " id="sidebar-menu-1">
  {% for category in category_list %}
    <li class="c-dropdown c-active c-open">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="c-toggler">{{ category.grouper|capfirst }} <span class="c-arrow"></span> </a>
      <ul class="c-dropdown-menu">
        {% for p in parts %}
          {% if p.category == category.grouper %}
          <li>
            <a href="{% url 'part_detail' category=p.category slug=p.slug %}">{{ p.title }}</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Screenshot of Local View(displays correctly)**
[image]

Comment: Could it be something as easily overlooked as your production db has duplicated categories/parts?

Comment: Well that would just be ridiculous :)  Good idea; I'll check.

Comment: Just checked the database and there are no duplicates.

Comment: hmm, could you post your template code where you have the include?

Comment: Hi Jeff, here is the template include `{% include 'includes/parts_sidebar.html' %}` nothing out of the ordinary and works as it should in my local environment.  I am using PostgreSQL and exported my production database so I could import locally, so both are using the same database but is it possible for the database to allow previously deleted objects?  Would reindexing my production database be safe to try?

Comment: It shouldn't be allowing previously deleted objects but honestly I'm out of ideas on what could be causing this - could it be cache related? A reindex should be fine but as always backup beforehand etc

Comment: @jeff_hd Thank you for your help; I sorted it out and posted the answer.  It was a `regroup` configuration issue, not a database issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the correct code. It wasn't repeating as I thought it was, it was just iterating through my categories from the top down, and then grouping them by categories as they were positioned on the list, which is why I was getting duplicate categories.  Adding `|dictsort:"category.slug"` to my regroup tag and `.list` in my `for` loop fixed the issue.

```
{% regroup tools|dictsort:"category.slug" by category as grouped %}
<ul class="c-sidebar-menu collapse " id="sidebar-menu-1">
  {% for category in grouped %}
    <li class="c-dropdown c-active c-open">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="c-toggler">{{ category.grouper|capfirst }} <span class="c-arrow"></span> </a>
      <ul class="c-dropdown-menu">
        {% for t in category.list %}
          {% if t.category == category.grouper %}
          <li>
            <a href="{% url 'tool_detail' category=t.category slug=t.slug %}">{{ t.title }}</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```